# How to update an imageView source onPostResult of async task in BaseAdapter class

Tags: android, android-layout, android-adapter, android-adapterview

I want to update an image view source after downloading in `OnPostExecute` method in `async` method

Here is `getView` method of my base adapter class

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    vi = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView==null){

        /****** Inflate tabitem.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) *******/
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_single_message, null);
        /****** View Holder Object to contain tabitem.xml file elements ******/

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.chatText = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.singleMessage);
        holder.imageView=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image);
        holder.videoIcon=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.video_icon);
        holder.singleMessageContainer=(LinearLayout)vi.findViewById(R.id.singleMessageContainer);
        holder.singleMessageImageContainer=(LinearLayout)vi.findViewById(R.id.singleMessageImageContainer);
        holder.dwnld_btn = (Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.download_btn);

        /************  Set holder with LayoutInflater ************/
        vi.setTag( holder );
    }
    else
        holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();

    if(data.size()<=0)
    {
        holder.chatText.setText("Start new conversation!");


    }
    else
    {
        /***** Get each Model object from Arraylist ********/
        tempValues=null;
        tempValues = (ChatMessage) data.get(position);
        //Toast.makeText(activity, "MimeType = " + tempValues.getMessageText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        String path = tempValues.getMediaURL();
        String mediaMIMEType = tempValues.getMediaMIMEType();
        int isDownload = tempValues.getIsDownloaded();
        String senderUserInfoId = tempValues.getSenderUserInfoId();

if(!tempValues.getSenderUserInfoId().equals(loginUserInfoId) && mediaMIMEType.contains("IMAGE"))
        {
            holder.chatText.setPadding(30,10,10,10);
            holder.chatText.setMaxWidth(550);
            holder.chatText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.chat_rightpng);
            holder.chatText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));//.setTextColor(R.color.white);
            holder.chatText.setText(tempValues.getMessageText());

            holder.singleMessageContainer.setGravity(true ? Gravity.LEFT : Gravity.RIGHT);

            try {
                holder.imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.videoIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                if(isDownload == 0) {
                    holder.dwnld_btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    holder.imageView.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
                    holder.imageView.setMaxWidth(450);
                    holder.imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#005684"));
                    holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.blur);
                }
                else {
                    holder.dwnld_btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    holder.imageView.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
                    holder.imageView.setMaxWidth(450);
                    holder.imageView.setMaxWidth(550);
                    holder.imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#005684"));
                    holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(path));
                }

                holder.singleMessageImageContainer.setGravity(true ? Gravity.LEFT : Gravity.RIGHT);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                //txtUrl.setText("Error: Exception");
            }
        }


            } catch(Exception e) {
                //txtUrl.setText("Error: Exception");
            }
        }

        /******** Set Item Click Listner for LayoutInflater for each row *******/
        holder.dwnld_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnDownloadBtnClickListener(position));
    }
    return vi;
}
```

Here is click function when I am clicking on download button

```
private class OnDownloadBtnClickListener  implements View.OnClickListener {
    private int mPosition;

    OnDownloadBtnClickListener(int position){
        mPosition = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        final ChatMessage val = ( ChatMessage ) data.get(mPosition);
        if(isInternetOn()) {
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
            downlodedMsgId = val.getId();
            if (val.getMediaMIMEType().contains("IMAGE")) {
                localFileURL = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "/Planetskool/Media/Images/IMG_" + timeStamp + ".png";

                new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(val.getOnlineMediaURL());

        }
    }
}
```

Here is `async` method to download a file where in `OnPostExecute` I want to change the source of `imageview`

```
class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread
     * Show Progress Bar Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Downloading file. Please wait...");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressDialog.setMax(100);
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        progressDialog.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    /**
     * Downloading file in background thread
     * */
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
        int count;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();
            // getting file length
            int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

            // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

            // Output stream to write file
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(localFileURL);

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                // publishing the progress....
                // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));

                // writing data to file
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            // flushing output
            output.flush();

            // closing streams
            output.close();
            input.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Updating progress bar
     * */
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        progressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task
     * Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        db.updateDownlodedPath(downlodedMsgId, localFileURL);
        updateResults(data);
        localFileURL = "";
        downlodedMsgId = 0;
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

Comment: Which imageview are you talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your clickListner as

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        final ChatMessage val = ( ChatMessage ) data.get(mPosition);
        if(isInternetOn()) {
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
            downlodedMsgId = val.getId();
            if (val.getMediaMIMEType().contains("IMAGE")) {
                localFileURL = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "/Planetskool/Media/Images/IMG_" + timeStamp + ".png";

                new DownloadFileFromURL(position).execute(val.getOnlineMediaURL());

        }
    }
```

and create constructor in AsyncTask as

```
 class DownloadFileFromURL(int mPosition){
         //get your imageViewByPosition here and change the url in OnPostExecute Method
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First you have to check whether the position where you want to display image is visible in your listview, if is visible then update it or else save it in any preferred location you want (file or Lrucache ).

The method to check whether the position is visible or not is given below

```
public synchronized void onThumbnailReceived(Bitmap thumnail, String path) {
    if(listview!= null)
    {
    final int numVisibleChildren = listview.getChildCount();
    final int firstVisiblePosition = listiew
            .getFirstVisiblePosition();

    for (int i = firstVisiblePosition; i < firstVisiblePosition + numVisibleChildren; i++) {

        if (data.get(i).get(IMAGEPATH).toString()
                .equals(path)) {
            View view = listview.getChildAt(i - firstVisiblePosition);
            getView(i, view, null);
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: call this method from on postexecute